# How to create a method which prints the entire Request and Response in Play?

Tags: playframework-2.6

I want to create a helper method which could be called from a `Controller` and prints the different parameters of the `Request`. I tried to do something like following but I need to pass type parameter to `Request`. What should I pass for type parameter?

```
import play.api.mvc.Request

package object utilities {

  def printPlayHttpRequest (request:Request): Unit ={ //Request needs type parameter. What should I pass as type parameter?

  }
}
```

Looking at the `apply` method of `Request` object, it seems that the type parameter passed corresponds to the Body type. So do I need to pass some body type?

```
def apply[A](rh: RequestHeader, body: A): Request[A]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Play documentation, I suppose the `A` in `Request[A]` corresponds to type of body and it could be any Scala type as the request body, for example String, NodeSeq, Array[Byte], JsonValue, or java.io.File, as long as we have a body parser able to process it

From documentation

```
Previously we said that an Action was a Request => Result function. This is not entirely true. Let’s have a more precise look at the Action trait:

trait Action[A] extends (Request[A] => Result) {
  def parser: BodyParser[A]
}

First we see that there is a generic type A, and then that an action must define a BodyParser[A]. With Request[A] being defined as:

trait Request[+A] extends RequestHeader {
  def body: A
}

The A type is the type of the request body. We can use any Scala type as the request body, for example String, NodeSeq, Array[Byte], JsonValue, or java.io.File, as long as we have a body parser able to process it.

To summarize, an Action[A] uses a BodyParser[A] to retrieve a value of type A from the HTTP request, and to build a Request[A] object that is passed to the action code.
```

Following is my implementation

```
import play.api.mvc.{AnyContent, Request}

package object utilities {

  def printPlayHttpRequest (request:Request[AnyContent]): Unit ={
    println(s"Attr: ${request.attrs}, \n Body: ${request.body},  \n connection: ${request.connection},  \n headers: ${request.headers},  \n method: ${request.method}, \n target:  ${request.target},  \n version: ${request.version},  \n mediatype: ${request.mediaType}")
  }
}
```